# Wildfly 8.2 not recognising spring module

Tags: spring, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am getting exception
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.springframework.sp
ring:main"}}}}

I defined spring modules as per the link 
    http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/add-apache-camel-and-spring-as-jboss-modules-in-wildfly.html

but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because typo in filename it is not modules.xml it should be module.xml